# What is the difference between “ändern” and “verändern”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, usage

I'm still confused about the difference between *ändern* and *verändern*. I have read something about *ändern* only being used with small changes and *verändern* when something changes totally. But where exactly is the line between those?
And how does this work when we talk about a person being changed instead of a thing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Persons as objects of change:

**Ändern** is used in the sense of changing someone's defining personality traits (which is often seen as hopeless):

> • Er ist ein Dickkopf – ich kann ihn nicht *ändern*. – He's a pighead, I can't change him.
>
> • Der kleine Junge ist streitsüchtig. Ich hoffe, dass er sich noch
> *ändert*. – The boy is always looking for a fight. I hope he'll change.
>
> • Früher war ich immer betrunken. Aber jetzt habe ich mich *geändert*. – Before, I was always drunk. But now I have changed.

**Verändern** would be used in the context of changing a person's entire life and/or occupational condition:

> • Ich möchte mich (beruflich) *verändern*. – I want to do something
> else. (This can refer to a change of position or industry.)

Typically in a Perfekt construction:

> • Er *hat* sich *verändert*. Er ist nicht mehr so, wie er früher war. – He has
> changed. He's not the same anymore.
>
> • Du *hast* dich seit damals gar nicht *verändert*. – You haven't changed a bit since that time.
>
> • Du *hast* mich *verändert*. – You have changed me. (You've been this
> important to my life.)
>
> • Im Laufe der Jahre *habe* ich mich vollkommen *verändert*. – Through the
> years, I have totally changed.

Comment: Is then the correct verb is "sich verändern"? Or does verändern can stand on its own?

Comment: 'Verändern' is also used without 'sich', as it is *not a real reflexive verb*. (e.g.: Wir verändern die Reihenfolge der Zahlen.—We alter the sequence of the numbers). The reflexive pronoun is only used when the sentence's subject itself is the object of the verb 'verändern'.

Comment: Jemand, der früher immer betrunken war, aber jetzt nicht mehr, hat sich in meinen Augen verändert. Auch unten: "Er hat sich verändert (usw.)" - ob "Er hat sich geändert (usw.)" nicht auch funktioniert wird gar nicht geprüft. Soll das ein Vergleich sein? Confirmationbias.

Answer (score 9):

The difference between these words lies in *intention*, *specifics*, *duration* and *size* of change:

### ändern

Intentional, specific, instantaneous, huge change or replacement:

> - In den Jahren habe ich mich (bewusst) geändert. - *intentional*
> - (Genau) Das ändert alles! - *specific*
> - Ändere es (die Anzahl)! - *specific*
> - Die Temparatur ändert sich (jetzt). - *instantaneous*
> - Wir haben die Farben (komplett) geändert. - *huge*
> - Er änderte die Basis (auf eine Alternative). - *replacement*

### verändern

Unconscious, unspecific, process, small change:

> - In den Jahren habe ich mich (ohne es zu bemerken) verändert. (unintentional)
> - Das verändert (irgendwie) alles. - *unspecific*
> - Verändere es (irgendwas)! - *unspecific*.
> - Die Temparatur verändert sich (seit letztem Jahr). - *continuous*
> - Wir haben die Farbe (leicht) verändert. - *small*

Answer (score 3):

The word  “ändern” refers to "changing" something by *adding* something different or leading someone in a new direction. In essence, you are changing the "mix," rather than the underlying object. This is sometimes referred to as "retail" change.

On the other hand “verändern” has the connotation of changing something by *replacing* what's already there. In the context of a person, you are "re-making" or replacing him, rather than "leading in a new direction." That is sometimes referred to as "wholesale" change.

Comment: "Wieso fahren wir jetzt schneller?" "Wir haben die Richtung verändert". "Können Sie die Hose ändern; unten etwas kürzen?" Welcher Mix? Im Kontext der Person wird also jemand getötet und neu gemacht? Alles Humbug! Unhinterfragte Ad-hoc-Ideen, nicht mal gute.

Comment: @userunknown: If you alter a Hose, it's still the same piece of cloth, hence andern." If you replace a person, that's "verandern." "Remaking" him or her would be an intermediate case, but probably closer to "verandern."

Comment: This is a wrong answer. "Du hast dich irgendwie verändert" - clearly nothing was replaced here.

Comment: @svenmeier: Du hast dich irgendwie verandert," you have "changed" by replacing a behavior or an attribute with a new one. It does not have to be a physical change.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, ändern refers to something being changed or altered. Verändern refers to something being transformed or transmuted. Eg In der katholischen Kirche werden das Brot und der Wein in den Körper und das Blut Christi verändert, aber in der evangelischen Kirche ändern sich das Brot und der Wein symbolisch in den Körper und das Blut Christi.

Comment: Willkommen! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have understood it correctly. There is no defined line between those two words. Where you use one, you usually can use the other. It's more of a point of what you want to embrace.

**Ändern**: quite neutral. it/he/she/whatever "changed".

**Verändern**: if you want to say that something *really* changed, or put attention on the change if that is your point.

**Abändern**: to put attention that it is now different from before. I think this is not used for people.

Comment: The words are not interchangeable. There is a significant difference between “er hat sich verändert” and “er hat sich geändert” when talking about a person, such as a teenager. The former typically means “his appearance changed” while the latter means “his attitude/behavior changed”.