# Difference between "ändern" and "verändern"

Tags: vocabulary

I am aware that this same question has been asked here: [What is the difference between “ändern” and “verändern”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5898/what-is-the-difference-between-%c3%a4ndern-and-ver%c3%a4ndern), however the issue remains at large for me. Basically, from this post specifically, apparently "ändern" is used more for "casual" changes, in the sense of effecting a change onto something pre-existing, whereas "verändern" implies a more severe modification, even suggesting total replacement. HOWEVER, this seems to be a point of contention, as some posts on other forums suggest the complete opposite while even others back up the link's conclusion. So, my question is: what gives? What are their differences? Is this a regional thing? Are they really just interchangeable and some people grow fond of one more than the other? Thanks.

Links to the other posts:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C3%A4ndern-ver%C3%A4ndern.80337/ (opposite)

http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,49568,49580,quote=1 (this one talks about active/on purpose vs. passive)

http://www.grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?480-Gibt-es-einen-Unterschied-zwischen-quot-%E4ndern-quot-und-quot-ver%E4ndern-quot-und-wie-lie%DFe-sich-dieser-erkl%E4ren (somewhat opposite, does say "ändern" can be used for full on exchanges/replacements)

http://deutschhappen.com/wann-verwendet-man-das-verb-andern-wann-verandern (complete opposite)

https://www.italki.com/question/88674 (apparently doesn't make much of a distinction, simply states that "verändern" is used less frequently).

Comment: Can you provide to the post on other forums where the opposite is suggested?

Comment: As requested, included the links

Comment: Richtig ist, dass die Antworten dort alle unbefriedigende Kaffeesatzleserei sind. Man denkt sich ein paar Beispielsätze aus, und behandelt die zufälligen Unterschiede als essentiellen Unterschied, meist ohne die Gegenprobe überhaupt zu machen. Diesmal wird es nicht besser laufen.

Answer (score 4):

The prefix *ver-* in a lot of cases is either an intensifier or a switch of perspective.

> *reisen* (to travel) → *verreisen* (to go on a journey)
>
> *reißen* (to tear) → *verreißen* (to slate something)
>
> *brauchen* (to need) → *verbrauchen* (to consume)
>
> *lassen* (to let) → loslassen (to let go) → *verlassen* (to leave a place, to leave someone)
>
> *mieten* (to rent) → *vermieten* (to rent out)
>
> *tun* (to do) → *vertun* (to do wrong)

(There are also cases where *ver-* changes the meaning completely as with *mögen* or *machen* and cases like *verzeihen* or *verletzen* where the unprefixed verb does not exist.)

*Ändern* is complicated. For example you could say:

> Wir müssen etwas ändern.

*We have to change something.*

That one is neutral. However

> Wir müssen etwas verändern.

*We (really) have to change something.*

puts some pressure into the sentence.

When your loved one says to you

> Du hast dich geändert.

*You have changed.*

she usually means a neutral or positive change. While

> Du hast dich verändert.

means your change puts stress on her.

Sometimes *verändern* belongs to fixed phrases as

> Ich wollte mich verändern.

*I wanted to switch.* (usually a job, or move into a house instead of a flat)

You cannot use *ändern* in such phrases.

So, as a general rule, *verändern* means to change more than usual, change that needs some work, or change in an undesireable fashion (or in desireable fashion if the current condition is undesireable). Which is what *ver-* does to a lot of words. With *ändern* the difference is very subtle.

Comment: "Ich schwöre, ich werde mich ändern! Ab morgen nur noch upvotes für alle!" Kann man schon sagen. Verändern ginge auch. Und nein, eine Faustregel kann ich nicht angeben. :) Ob *verändern* oder *ändern* sagt nichts darüber, ob es zum positiven oder zum negativen ist (was wäre denn, wenn Du es weiter bestreitest, mit "nicht geändert/nicht verändert"? Das macht alles eine tadelnde oder lobende Stimme, die man für beides nutzen kann. Ebenso ist *really* change something Unfug. Du unterliegst, wie so viele hier, dem Confirmationbias: Eine erste Eingebung wird nicht kritisch zu widerlegen versucht.

Comment: Es handelt sich um konkrete Beispiele die üblicherweise genau in diesem Sinne benutzt werden. Und nicht andersherum. Eingeleitet von der Feststellung, dass *ändern* kompliziert sei und schließend mit der Feststellung dass man über *verändern* nicht mehr sagen könne als dass die als Veränderung stärker empfunden/beschrieben wird als mit *ändern* oder dass sie sogar als negativ empfunden wird. Du unterliegst, wie so viele hier, dem Confirmationbias: Eine erste Eingebung wird nicht kritisch zu widerlegen versucht.

Comment: Woran erkennen wir denn, dass in "Wir müssen etwas verändern" mehr Druck ist als in "Wir müssen etwas ändern"?

Comment: *Änderung* wird immer dann benutzt, wenn keine zusätzliche Wertung transportiert werden soll. So wäre z.B. eine *Veränderungsschneiderei* doch etwas ungewöhnlich. Darunter stellte ich mir vor, dass die meine Kleider nicht nur kürzen, sondern was ganz anderes daraus machen. Ebenso heißt es *Änderungsvorschlag* und nicht etwa *Veränderungsvorschlag*, um der Sache die Spitze zu nehmen.

Comment: Das würde dann doch eher darauf hinweisen, dass eine _Veränderung_ stärker qualitativ ändert als eine _Änderung_. Außerdem scheint mir der Unterschied bei den -ung-Bildungen eher zu sein, dass wir _Änderung_ sagen, wenn jemand etwas ändert, und _Veränderung_, wenn etwas (oder jemand) sich ändert. (Womit wir auch die _Änderungsschneiderei_ und den _Änderungsvorschlag_ hätten.

Comment: Richtig. Die Änderung ist beim *Verändern* qualitativ anders. Schrieb ich bereits in meiner Ursprungsantwort, mit einer anderen Perpektive auf die Sache und tendentiell größer. Wegen der Problematik von *etwas ändern* und *sich ändern* hatte ich *Du hast dich geändert.* vs. *Du hast dich verändert.* als Beispiel gebracht. Auch da ist es ein qualitativer Unterschied der Änderung, nicht bloß eine Grammatikfrage.

Comment: Heißt das, du meinst _qualitativ_, wenn du _wertend_ sagst, oder sind das zwei unterschiedliche Dimensionen, die da beide miteinfließen?

Comment: Ohne Wertung oder mit Wertung ist ein qualitativer Unterschied.

Answer (score 3):

The one thing that rings true in your links is that you cannot use "verändern" to mean *switch out*:

- "Er hat seinen Therapeuten geändert." - This is ambiguous: He could have produced a change in his therapis or he could have exchanged his therapist for another.
- "Er hat seinen Therapeuten verändert." - This can, as far as I can tell, only mean that he brought about some change in his therapist.

Thus, you can only say "die Richtung ändern", because you cannot bring about a change in the direction - its only property is being that direction, so any  change is going to exchange the direction for another. Same with "seine Adresse ändern", where "verändern" would sound like you stay in the same place but make a change to the address itself.

In examples where I mean to change a thing (without switching it out), I don't think that there is any semantic difference between the two. I would usually use "verändern", except in set phrases, and I think that that is the general tendency, but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly true that "ändern" and "verändern" are close semantically, and are in some instances synonymous.

My understanding is that the **context determines the word** (ie. the collocation). That is, one of them is required when using certain other words. Check out, for instance, the detailed DWDS corpus entries for [ändern](https://www.dwds.de/wp/%C3%A4ndern) vs. [verändern](https://www.dwds.de/wp/ver%C3%A4ndern). See also the comparison page [here](https://www.dwds.de/wp?q=%C3%A4ndern&comp-method=diff&comp=&limit=100&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&view=table).

I do observe two tendencies from that data: first, ändern is the more commonly used word. Second, verändern takes on the meaning of "*to modify*" or "to change a detail" more often than does ändern, although both may. An example for this confusion is:

> Wir haben den Plan geändert.

Literally, this means that "we" have changed our plan, but not entirely (I'd have used "wir haben den Plan gewechselt" or "wir haben einen anderen Plan verwendet") but also not only a detail (which would be "wir haben den (bestehenden) Plan verändert", note the clarifying "bestehend", ie. *existing*).

With the corpus data above, we (I, really) see that "ändern" is far more likely to occur with "Plan" than does "verändern", but that the latter is not uncommon. The example of "Grundriss" shows this more clearly: the *footprint* of a building, while a type of "Plan", is almost exclusively used with "verändern", owing perhaps to the difficulty of wholly altering one, making it easier to modify details in comparison.