# Unterschied ungeändert und unverändert

Tags: difference, usage, phrase, grammaticality

Mich wundert es, ob der englische Ausdruck

> *to give someone a surprise*

auch ungeändert/unverändert im Deutschen gebraucht werden kann. Also:

> *jemandem eine Überrasschung geben/bereiten*

Kenne nämlich auch nicht den Unterschied zwischen ungeändert und unverändert. Ich bitte um Erläuterung.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please, take the tour and mind the principle here that one question should be just that: one question - and choosing a fitting, descriptive title for a single problem should then be easy.

Comment: Auf Englisch schon hier beantwortet: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5898/what-is-the-difference-between-%c3%a4ndern-and-ver%c3%a4ndern

Answer (score 1):

Es heißt "jemandem eine Überraschung bereiten". Wenn **es** eine Überraschung gibt, dann werden wir jemandem ein Geschenk geben. Oder es gibt eine böse Überraschung, wenn der Gast nicht kommt. Aber wir können nicht jemandem eine Überraschung geben.